# Datatables.js excel export saving as Cherokee currency

Tags: excel, datatables

We're using the DataTables.js buttons to export data, using the "excel" extend function:

```
buttons: [{
                    extend: "excel",
                    text: "Excel",
                    filename: "VehiclesTable" + Math.random().toString().substring(0,12),
                    customize: function (xlsx) {
                        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                        //TODO:???
                    }
                }
            ],
```

...and it mostly works, however, any time we export data containing US currency, it correctly sets it as currency type, but uses the "Cherokee, United States" symbol as opposed to just "$" or "English, United States"

Cherokee, United States formats currency as "123.45 $" rather than "$123.45"

[image: Excel Screenshot]